# Is programmatically creating Google Custom Search Engines no longer possible?

Tags: google-oauth, google-custom-search

The documentation to Create Custom Search Engines Programmatically (https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/api) is no longer correct.

For authentication it states:

Although the Accounts Authentication API supports multiple authentication methods, Custom Search only supports `ClientLogin`...  When you make a request to ClientLogin, provide the service name for Custom Search, which is `cprose`.

If you follow the ClientLogin link you see that it is deprecated in favour of using OAuth2.0 for authentication.The documentation for *that* says you need to specify scope (rather than service), but looking through the list of OAuth2.0 scopes, there is none for Custom Search.

Does that mean that it is no longer possible to programmatically create CSE's?

Comment: it will probably still work with oauth2 just get an access token.   In the case where there is no scope for a api it normally just doesn't require a scope.     Note: I am guessing I haven't tried.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried and concluded that it is no longer possible, even though the old docs are still up. To test the api I used https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/, manually added https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cse as the scope, authenticated myself, then tested the api as per the docs. Requests return 302s pointing to the https URLs (docs use http), then using https all requests return 400. I wish they'd take down the documentation...

Comment: They've (sometime in the past couple months) removed that doc page. I guess instead of fixing the auth, they just removed the dos saying you can do it. It appears to be no longer possible.